# Find $\mathbb E(\tau)$ where $\tau=\operatorname{min}[t>1:X_{n+t}>\operatorname{max}[X_1,...,X_n]]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, order-statistics

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables with a given
>   continuous distribution function $F(x)=\mathbb P(X_i\le x), x>0$ and
>   $F(0)=0$. The values $X_1,...,X_n$ have been recorded.
>
> Let $Y_n=\operatorname{max}[X_1,...,X_n]$.
>
> Let $\tau=\operatorname{min}[t>1:X_{n+t}>Y_n]$
>
> Find $\mathbb E(\tau)$

We have shown that $\mathbb P( \tau=k)=\frac n{(k+n-1)(k+n)}$ but surely we then have $$\mathbb E(\tau)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k\space\mathbb P(\tau=k)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{kn}{(k+n-1)(k+n)}$$
but now in the case $n=1$ (and the question gives no indication that we cannot consider $n=1$) don't we have: $$\mathbb E(\tau)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac 1{k+1}?$$

This must be wrong but I don't see where.

Any help with the question or where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your computations are correct and show that $E(\tau)$ is infinite for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. The question poses the $X_i$ as yearly rainfall and $Y_n$ is a dam. It defies my intuition that we do not have a finite expectation- that we will never surpass $Y_n$ regardless of how the $X_i$ are distributed.

Comment: Of course we will surpass $Y_n$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb E(\tau)$ being infinite not suggest that the expected number of years before we pass $Y_n$ is infinite?

Comment: Yeah, the **expected** number of years is infinite but the number of years is almost surely finite.